# should I let my opencv calibration program set my camera intrinsic K value, specifically Cx and Cy, or do it manually?

Tags: c++, opencv, math, camera, camera-calibration

K(intrinsic parameter) from opencv calibration is CX = 378.322 and CY = 222.498. Imager resolution is 752 (H) x 480(V), divided by 2, = 376 and 240 respectively. I'm not saying it shouldn't be that but I am wondering because I have seen instances in which people just manually set CX and CY to exactly 1/2 imager vertical max and 1/2 imager horizontal max. Should I do the same or use all of K values to work using calibrated CX, CY.?

Comment: You should use the values obtained from calibration. Cx, Cy are not always and not for all cameras exactly half of width and height.

Comment: Thanks for dispelling the ambiguity of  its use. Do I need to use K with OpenCV SolvePnP any time I use an OpenCV transformation matrix or any use thereof?

Comment: yes, use K from calibration.